# How to make the basic inverted index program more pythonic

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, inverted-index

I have code for an invertedIndex as follows. However I'm not too satisfied with it and was wondering how it can be made more compact and pythonic

```
class invertedIndex(object):


  def __init__(self,docs):
     self.docs,self.termList,self.docLists=docs,[],[]

     for index,doc in enumerate(docs):

        for term in doc.split(" "):
            if term in self.termList:
                i=self.termList.index(term)
                if index not in self.docLists[i]:
                    self.docLists[i].append(index)

            else:
                self.termList.append(term)
                self.docLists.append([index])  

  def search(self,term):
        try:
            i=self.termList.index(term)
            return self.docLists[i]
        except:
            return "No results"





docs=["new home sales top forecasts june june june",
                     "home sales rise in july june",
                     "increase in home sales in july",
                     "july new home sales rise"]

i=invertedIndex(docs)
print invertedIndex.search("sales")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the doc indicies in a Python [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and use a dict to reference the "doc set" for each term.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class invertedIndex(object):

  def __init__(self,docs):
      self.docSets = defaultdict(set)
      for index, doc in enumerate(docs):
          for term in doc.split():
              self.docSets[term].add(index)

  def search(self,term):
        return self.docSets[term]

docs=["new home sales top forecasts june june june",
                     "home sales rise in july june",
                     "increase in home sales in july",
                     "july new home sales rise"]

i=invertedIndex(docs)
print i.search("sales") # outputs: set([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

`set` works a bit like a list, but is unordered and cannot contain duplicate entries.

`defaultdict` is basically a `dict`, which has a default type when no data is available (in this case an empty set).

Comment: The defaultdict(set) is a neat way

Answer (score 2):

This solution is almost identical to @Peter Gibson's. In this version, the index *is* the data, there's no delegated *docSets* object involved.  This makes the code slightly shorter and clearer.

The code also preserves the original order of the documents... which is sort of a bug, I like Peter's `set()` implementation better.

Note also that reference to an non existent term, like `ix['garbage']`, implicitly modifies the index.  If the only API is `search`, this is fine, but this case is worth noting.

### source

```
class InvertedIndex(dict):
    def __init__(self, docs):
        self.docs = docs

        for doc_index,doc in enumerate(docs):
            for term in doc.split(" "):
                self[term].append(doc_index)

    def __missing__(self, term):
        # operate like defaultdict(list)
        self[term] = []
        return self[term]

    def search(self, term):
        return self.get(term) or 'No results'


docs=["new home sales top forecasts june june june",
      "home sales rise in july june",
      "increase in home sales in july",
      "july new home sales rise",
      'beer',
      ]

ix = InvertedIndex(docs)
print ix.__dict__
print
print 'sales:',ix.search("sales")
print 'whiskey:', ix.search('whiskey')
print 'beer:', ix.search('beer')

print '\nTEST OF KEY SETTING'
print ix['garbage']
print 'garbage' in ix
print ix.search('garbage')
```

### output

```
{'docs': ['new home sales top forecasts june june june', 'home sales rise in july june', 'increase in home sales in july', 'july new home sales rise', 'beer']}

sales: [0, 1, 2, 3]
whiskey: No results
beer: [4]

TEST OF KEY SETTING
[]
True
No results
```

Comment: subclassing dict is a nice solution - you get things like `__str__, __repr__, __eq__` etc for free

Comment: Thanks both of you guys. I'm trying next to write the Vector Space Model as concise as possible and will use these approaches

Comment: I have a follow up question for shavenwarthog.
With this approach how do I restrict setting of keys from outside this class. For eg
If someone did ix["garbage"], it would add an empty list to the ix object as { "garbage"=[]}. This is not desirable

Comment: @sarathjoseph, hmm, yes.  I understand that this isn't desirable, but what is the overall use case? I thought the API was `ix.search('garbage')`, which provides `"No results"` as expected.  I've updated the code and output to illustrate.

Comment: The search behaves just as expected.It shouldn't be too much of a problem and I might just get things working. But is there a way to keep the ix object free of other keys but the terms.